# How to replace the "checkered" background shown during orientation changing in Mobile Safari (iPad)?

Tags: ipad, rotation, orientation, mobile-safari

I am developing a small web application optimized for iPad (using mainly javascript & CSS quirks and hacks). However, there is an issue that I just can not find or come up how to resolve.

The thing is that if I change the orientation of the iPad, during the rotation animation a transparent ("checkered") background is shown in the places that were not rendered in previous orientation. One guy on forums.macrumors.com [posted an excellent screenshot illustrating this behavior](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1176592). The thing is, since my application  has a rather dark look and & feel, this checkered background showing during the rotation seems to be awkwardly out of place.

However, this guy's screenshot was for the iPhone - that said, and considering that stackoverflow.com is more programming-focused, I thought I'd ask if anyone struggled with and, hopefully, successfully resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari displays the checkered background when the rendering can't keep up (try scrolling really fast). As far as I know there is no way of changing the pattern.